# How to perform a "selective color adjustment" (a Photoshop feature) in GIMP?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

Cf. [How to perform a "selective color adjustment" (a Photoshop feature) in Darktable?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/163235/how-to-perform-a-selective-color-adjustment-a-photoshop-feature-in-darktable)

---

Photoshop lets you pick one of the nine colors (which are the main colors of the three color systems CMYK, RGB and Grayscale), and adjust the Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and Black values for this one (1/9) chosen color [note the plural form in the screenshot: e.g., it's not the single color of "green" but the color range (?) of "greens"].

Are there any good ways of doing something equivalent in GIMP ?

[image]

*Note that "Hue/Saturation" and "Selective Color Adjustment" is [not the same thing in Photoshop, apparently](https://lensvid.com/post-processing/photoshop/which-is-better-hue-saturation-vs-selective-color-in-photoshop/).*

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner.

---

PS: Specifically, I'm interested selecting the "**blacks**" (only) and changing the values of Cyan (+), Magenta (+) and Yellow (-), to give the blacks a bit of **blueish**-tint.

---

Related links:

- https://rahagfx-com.translate.goog/photoshop/%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%B8%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA-selective-color-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%BE/?_x_tr_sl=iw&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp
- https://shotkit.com/selective-color-photoshop/
- https://lensvid.com/post-processing/photoshop/which-is-better-hue-saturation-vs-selective-color-in-photoshop/

Comment: Hi. There's no direct equivalent to Photoshop's Selective Colour adjustment in GIMP. You can use GIMP's Hue-Saturation and Colour Balance adjustments instead for similar results. When learning GIMP, forget Photoshop. Look up tutorials on GIMP instead.

Comment: Also note that GIMP's Hue-Saturation, although similar, is not quite same as the Hue-Saturation in Photoshop, so you aren't really comparing like with like anyway.

Comment: Perhaps [Color > Map > Rotate colors](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-filter-color-rotate.html) that lets you shift a range of hues to another range of hues?

Comment: There are also other methods to swap colours such as Colors > Map > Rotate Colors. This is a fairly powerful colour swap function when hue-saturation might not be enough. I found a [tutorial on youtube here](https://youtu.be/S3idTrbnggI?si=-XgACUm1JItbBEL8)

Comment: @xenoid -LOL we must have thought that at the same time!!

Comment: @billykerr Great minds...  

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your recent update. I think I can answer this now.  To adjust the blacks to make them have a blueish tint, use a curves adjustment. You can do this in GIMP or Photoshop. Both are similar.

[image]

If this isn't quite the shade of blue you want, you can also make curves adjustments for the red and green channels as well. Here you can see I have also added curves for the red and green channels.

[image]