# How to perform a "selective color adjustment" (a Photoshop feature) in Darktable?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, raw-format

Cf. [How to perform a "selective color adjustment" (a Photoshop feature) in GIMP?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/163229/how-to-perform-a-selective-color-adjustment-a-photoshop-feature-in-gimp)

---

Photoshop lets you pick one of the nine colors (which are the main colors of the three color systems CMYK, RGB and Grayscale), and adjust the Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and Black values for this one (1/9) chosen color [note the plural form in the screenshot: e.g., it's not the single color of "green" but the color range (?) of "greens"].

Are there any good ways of doing something equivalent in Darktable (e.g., with Darktable's "color zones" feature, with a RAW image) - or with a similar FOSS (such as RawTherapee or Digikam, and available plugins) ?

[image]

*Note that "Hue/Saturation" and "Selective Color Adjustment" is [not the same thing in Photoshop, apparently](https://lensvid.com/post-processing/photoshop/which-is-better-hue-saturation-vs-selective-color-in-photoshop/).*

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner.

---

PS: Specifically, I'm interested selecting the "**blacks**" (only) and changing the values of Cyan (+), Magenta (+) and Yellow (-), to give the blacks (and only the blacks) a bit of **blueish**-tint.

---

Related links:

- https://rahagfx-com.translate.goog/photoshop/%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%B8%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA-selective-color-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%BE/?_x_tr_sl=iw&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp
- https://shotkit.com/selective-color-photoshop/
- https://lensvid.com/post-processing/photoshop/which-is-better-hue-saturation-vs-selective-color-in-photoshop/

Comment: "to give the blacks (and only the blacks) a bit of blueish-tint."  use [Curves](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/4.0/en/darkroom/processing-modules/curves/) for this in Darktable. It's basically the same as the answer I gave in your other question for GIMP.  For more complex/targeted colour swapping, Darktable has [Color Zones](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/4.0/en/module-reference/processing-modules/color-zones/). See Color Zones [tutorial on Youtube](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/4.0/en/module-reference/processing-modules/color-zones/)